# Appending a numpy array to python list

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to append a numpy array to a list with float values but the result values are 1.
`z.append(ReLU(np.dot(batch_data,self.weights[0]) + self.bias[0])`
real value is eg. 3.678
but the corresponding value in list z is 1.0

Comment: Please provide a sample input and output for a [mcve]

Comment: Please try to post a sample code that allows us to reproduce the problem ourselves. In the very least, please provide comments about the variable and types in place and also dependant functions. For example, what's `ReLU` and what does it return?